# Engine block numbers

Tags: engine, chevrolet

My engine block numbers are C5F337147. I can't seem to find this number anywhere.  I was told it was a 350.  Was just trying to confirm and find out what year and what it might have come out of

Comment: Guess I should add it is currently in a 1971 Chevy c/k 20

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! That's not the block number ... look on the back left (driver's) side ... it should be a seven digit number starting with 39xxxxx. It will be casted into the block, not stamped.